# Are squares of two i.i.d normal distributions i.i.d?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let $X,Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ i.i.d. Correct me if I'm wrong, but $X^2,Y^2$ are also I.i.d.

Could I get advice on how to show this, or could someone let me know if this is difficult to show?

My thought was to find the PDFs of $X^2,Y^2$ and show that the definition of independence. I'm not quite sure how to get the pdfs , though. I was thinking looking at the mgf of $X^2$. However, if I get complicated pdfs then showing independence by definition seems like not the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent is equivalent to saying that for any Borel $f,g$, we have (if the expectations are defined)
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)] \tag{$\dagger$}.
$$

To show independence of $X^2,Y^2$, we use the same criterion. Let $f,g$ be two arbitrary Borel functions (and let $s$ denote the square function, $s\colon x\mapsto x^2$). Then $f^\prime=f\circ s$ and $g^\prime=g\circ s$ are Borel, so that with $(\dagger)$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[f'(X)g'(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f'(X)]\mathbb{E}[g'(Y)]
$$
(provided the expectations are well-defined). But that is exactly saying
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X^2)g(Y^2)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X^2)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y^2)]
$$ 
so (as $f,g$ were arbitrary) $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent.

To show that they have the same distribution, you can just say that for any $t \in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X^2 \leq t \} = \mathbb{P}\{Y^2 \leq t \}
$$
(same cumulative distribution function); this is trivial if $t<0$, and for $t\geq 0$ we have 
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X^2 \leq t \} = \mathbb{P}\{X \leq \sqrt{t} \}
= \mathbb{P}\{Y \leq \sqrt{t} \}
= \mathbb{P}\{Y^2 \leq t \}
$$
where in the middle we used that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed (so that their cumulative distribution functions are equal).

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Actually, is this necessarily true? That is, I'm not sure that $\mathbb{E}[f(X^2)g(Y^2)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X^2)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y^2)]$ implies that $X^2, Y^2$ are independent: They may simply be uncorrelated? [The answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/443659/265678) takes care of independence, though, if your method is not correct.

Comment: Well, this is a characterization of independence: two r.v.'s $X,Y$ are independent iff for all Borel $f,h$, $\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$ (whenever all expectations exist).