# Prove that if X, Y, Z independent, then X + Y and Z are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it possible to prove that if $X, Y, Z$ independent, then $X + Y$ and $Z$ are independent? Is it even true? Intuitively it seems true but I am unsure.

Answer (score 4):

By definition $X,Y,Z$ independent means $$P(X \in A, Y \in B, Z \in C) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)P(Z \in C).$$
In particular the pair $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$,
$$
P((X,Y) \in A \times B, Z \in C) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)P(Z \in C) = P((X,Y) \in A \times B) P(Z \in C).
$$
Then we note that if $U,V$ are independent, then $f(U), g(V)$ are independent for any borel $f,g$., see e.g. [If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443659/if-x-and-y-are-independent-then-fx-and-gy-are-also-independent/443691#443691)

Apply this to $U=(X,Y)$ and $V=Z$ with $f((X,Y)) = X+Y$ and $g(Z) = Z$ to find that $X+Y$ is independent of $Z$.

Comment: A priori, the fact that "the pair $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$" requires more than $P((X,Y) \in A \times B, Z \in C)$ being what you say--in other words, you should explain why what you say is enough for the pair $(X,Y)$ to be independent of $Z$.

Comment: @nullUser Could you explain a little bit about why $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$, considering the comment given by Did?

Comment: The definition of independence of $(X,Y)$ from $Z$ is that $P((X,Y) \in E, Z \in C) = P((X,Y) \in E)P(Z \in C)$ for all measurable $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The triple $X,Y,Z$ being an independent family by definition gives this when $E = A \times B$. The step I left out was that sets of the form $A\times B$ form a $\pi$-system generating the product $\sigma$-algebra, so if the independence formula holds for $E = A\times B$, then it will hold for all product measurable $E$.