# If X and Y are independent random variables, then, are X and $Z= Y+1$ independent random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I was trying to prove this statement in a formal way although intuitively it sounds true. 
is there any better and fast way to conclude this other than trying to see if the cumulative distribution function of $X, Z$ is equal to that of $X, Y$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8742/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/443659/321264.

Comment: The cdf of $(X,Z)$ is clearly _not_ the same as the cdf of$(X,Y)$. It's easy to show $X$ amd $Z$ are independent, using the _definition_ of independence.