# Expectation/ independence of random variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be two correlated variables and $Z\sim N(0,1)$ independent of $X,Y$. Consider the expectation:
$$E[f(X,Y)Z].$$
If $f(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent then clearly $E[f(X,Y)Z]=E[f(X,Y)]E[Z]=0$ but I guess this is not in general true. Nevertheless, I can argue as follows, by conditioning on $X$ and $Z$.
\begin{align*}
E[f(X,Y)Z]=& E[E[f(x,y)Z| X=x,Y=x]]\\
=&E\left[f(x,y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ze^{-z^2/2}dz \bigg|_{X=x,Y=y}\right]\\
=& 0.
\end{align*}

I really wonder where the error is! Could anyone help me? :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can delete a question, not vandalize it.

Comment: @egreg Is that a fact, that anybody can delete a question? I haven't asked any questions, but I had an *answer* I wanted to delete, and wasn't able to because I had no "delete" button. I assumed that was because I'm an unregistered user, and I guessed that deleting answers must be a privilege of registered users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your derivation. If Z is independent of (X,Y) then it is also independent of f(X,Y). Please, also see [Are functions of independent variables also independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this :) That's why I wanted to erase the post but I didn't know how to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: After I posted the answer, the question was removed. It is a good idea, even if you found the answer yourself, to include it here. Thanks.