# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, does it follow that $X^2$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If  $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then can I say that $X^2$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Any function of $X$ is independent of any function of $Y$.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if X and Y are independant, for all functions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, $\phi_1(X)$ and $\phi_2(Y)$ are independant.

Comment: thank you for the comment. you know where i can find proof to this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent
You can find different ideas of proofs in the answers of this question.