# Evaluating covariance for independent variables.

Tags: probability

Let $x_i,x_j$, two independent variables.

Consider this calculation:

$$\text{Cov}(x_i, x_ix_j) = E(x_i^2x_j) - E(x_i)E(x_ix_j) = E(x_i^2x_j) - E(x_i^2)E(x_j) \\= E(x_i^2)E(x_j) - E(x_i^2)E(x_j) = 0$$

Questions:

1. Why is true that $E(x_i)E(x_i) = E(x_i^2)$?
2. Why is true that $E(x_i^2x_j) = E(x_i^2)E(x_j)$. We don't know that $x_i^2$ and $x_j$ are independent.

Comment: 1) is true only if $Var(x_i) = 0$. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong. You have
$$
Cov ( X_i, X_iX_j) = E[X_i^2 X_j] - E[X_i]E[X_iX_j]
$$
since $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent we can split up the expected values:
$$
Cov ( X_i, X_iX_j) = E[X_i^2]E[ X_j] - E[X_i]^2 E[X_j]
$$
Observe the difference with your computations. The second term has the "square" outside. Finally you can write:
$$
Cov ( X_i, X_iX_j) = \left(E[X_i^2] - E[X_i]^2\right) E[X_j] = Var[X_i] E[X_j].
$$

Then the covariance is 0 if and only if, either $Var[X_i]=0$ or $E[X_j]=0$.

Conclusion:

1) It is not true.

2) Yes, they are of course still independent. Take a look at this post: [Are functions of independent variables also independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent)

Answer (score 1):

$E[X^2]\not = E[X]E[X]$ in general. Consider a random variable taking the values $-1$ and $+1$ with equal probability. Then $E[X]=0$ and $E[X^2]=1$.