# $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent implies $f(X_1, ... , X_k), X_{k+1}, ... , X_n$ are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables and let $f:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be some function.
Denote $Y=f(X_1, ..., X_k)$. Show that $Y, X_{k+1}, ... , X_n$ are independent.

I believe that the definition that should be used is that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent if and only if for every sets $A_1, ..., A_n$, it holds that 
$P(X_1\in A_1, ..., X_n\in A_n)=P(X_1\in A_1)...P(X_n\in A_n) $.

It's probably easy, but other than the case $k=1$ I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could prove it using the independence of $\sigma$-algebras.
See Theorem 52 from http://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~dlmcleis/s901/chapt3.pdf
and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent/8743#8743

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,\ A_{k+1},\ldots,A_{n}$ be [Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Write
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[f(X_1,\ldots,X_k)\in A, X_{k+1} \in A_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n \in A_{n}] = 
\mathbb{P}[(X_1,\ldots,X_k)\in f^{-1}(A), X_{k+1},\ldots,X_n)
\end{align}
Decompose $f^{-1}(A)\in \mathbb{R^k}$ to the cartesian product of $A_1,\ldots,A_k \in \mathbb{R}$, that is $f^{-1}(A) = A_1 \times \ldots \times A_k$.

Clearly \begin{equation}
(X_1,\ldots X_k) \in f^{-1}(A) \Leftrightarrow X_1\in A_1, \ldots, X_k \in A_k \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

Use (1) and the independence of $X_i,\ i = 1,\ldots n$ to deduce

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X_1 \in A_1, \ldots X_k \in A_k, X_{k+1}\in A_{k+1}, \ldots X_n \in A_n] &= \prod^k_{i=1} \mathbb{P}[X_{i} \in A_i] \cdot \prod^n_{i=k+1} \mathbb{P}[X_i \in A_i] \\
\end{align}
Finally using again (1) write
 \begin{equation}
\prod^k_{i=1} \mathbb{P}[X_{i} \in A_i] = \mathbb{P}[f(X_1,\ldots,X_k) \in A]
\end{equation}
proving that $f(X_1,\ldots X_k), X_{k+1}\ldots X_n$ are independent.

Comment: That was exactly my problem: I believe you can't just write the inverse image as a cartesian product. $f$ could be any function; what if it sends only vectors with all-entries-equal to $A$, for example? How would you decompose $f^{-1}(A)$ now?

Comment: @35T41 You're right. I cannot see how this proof could cover such cases.