# Variance and Conditional Expectation of combination of independent random variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, variance

Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent standard normal random variables,
$X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y\sim N(0, 1)$. Let $Z$ be a random variable defined by $Z = XY+2X$.

I have to find $\text{Var}(Z)$ and $\text{E}(Z|X)$.

$\text{Var}(Z)=\text{Var}(XY)+4\text{Var}(x)+2\text{Cov}(XY,Y)$

$\text{E}(Z|X)=\text{E}(XY|X)+2\text{E}(X|X)$

but still I don't know how to proceed further.

Can someone answer please? (Probably my question is very silly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**
$$
\operatorname{Var}Z=\operatorname EZ^2-(\operatorname EZ)^2
$$
$$
\operatorname E[XY]=\operatorname EX\operatorname EY
$$
$$
\operatorname E[X^2Y^2]=\operatorname EX^2\operatorname EY^2
$$
$$
\operatorname E(X\mid X)=X
$$
$$
\operatorname E(XY\mid X)=X\operatorname E(Y\mid X)
$$
$$
\operatorname E(Y\mid X)=\operatorname EY
$$

Comment: So if X and Y are independent, can I say that independence is invariant under non linear transformation? i.e. E[X$^2$Y]=E[X$^2$]E[Y]

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzoFlamini Yes (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent)).