# If $X_1, X_2 $ are independent RVs. then are ${X_1}^2$ and ${X_2}^2$ are independent?

Tags: probability

If $ X_1 , X_2 $ are independent RVs, then are ${X_1}^2 \,and\, {X_2}^2 $are independent?

P.S: this came up when i was working on the condition for which $Var({X_1 X_2})=Var({X_1}) Var({X_2})$

My Intuition says yes , but Covariance formula doesnt seem to work.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent where $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions. So your intuition is correct.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent