# Independence of two disjoint sums of independent Random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, marginal-probability

Suppose in a probability space $(X,\Omega,\mu)$, let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ be independent random variables. How do I prove that $X_1+X_2+...+X_{i-1}$ is independent of $X_i+...+X_n$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$ ?

Comment: Write down explicitly the definition of "independence of those two disjoint sums" and see if you can verify it. It may also help to write down explicitly the definition of "$X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent."

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrate that $X_a+X_b, X_c$ are independent if $X_a,X_b,X_c$ are mutually independent.

Use mathematical induction.

Comment: I got your point. But how can I show that $X_1+X_2$ independent of $X_3$ here ?