# Laplace transform of sum is product of Laplace transforms?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ iid random variables and $\lambda\ne 0$. Is it true that

$$E[e^{\lambda\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}]=\prod_{i=1}^n E[e^{\lambda X_i}]=\Big(E[e^{\lambda X_1}]\Big)^n,$$

by using independence or maybe another result in the first equation and identically distributed in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works exactly like that.

Since the variables $X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are independent, and each $e^{\lambda X_i}$ is a function of $X_i$ and no other $X_j$ with $j \neq i$, the variables $e^{\lambda X_i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are also independent. See, for example, [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent). This gives us

$$
E[e^{\lambda\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}]=E[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda X_i}]=\prod_{i=1}^n E[e^{\lambda X_i}].
$$

Next, as you already mentioned, we get from identical distribution of the $X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$

$$
E[e^{\lambda X_i}] = E[e^{\lambda X_1}] \qquad for \qquad 1 \leq i \leq n
$$

and thus

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n E[e^{\lambda X_i}]=\Big(E[e^{\lambda X_1}]\Big)^n,
$$

as desired.