# Why is this sequence of random variables pairwise independent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I have a sequence $(X_n: \Omega \to \mathbb{R})_{n=1}^\infty$ of pairwise independent random variables.

Define for $n \geq 1: X_n' := X_n I_{\{X_n \leq n\}}$ where $I_A$ is the indicator function on $A$. Is it true that $(X_n')_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of pairwise independent random variables?

Intuitively, this seems true. I know that pairwise independence is preserved under a Borel transformation $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so I tried to write

$$X_n' = g \circ X_n$$

for some suitable $g$ but did not come up with anything useful. Any hints?

Comment: It should follow from the definition of independent random variables. About your third  paragraph, are you sure that this result holds? I think $g$ needs to preserve measure or something like that.

Comment: $g$ must be measurable, which is what I meant with "Borel".

Comment: If $g$ is a constant you sure the claim holds?

Comment: I'm thinking about it. Give me a second please. Thanks for your useful comment.

Comment: Fix Borel sets $A,B$. We have to prove that $P(g\circ X \in A, g \circ Y \in B) = P(g \circ X \in A) P(g \circ Y \in B)$ where $g=1$ is the constant 1 function. If $1 \in A \cap B$, then we have $1 = 1$. Otherwise, we have $0=0$, so I don't think there is a contradiction. What do you think?

Comment: You're right constant random variables are independent of themselves. I'm still confused about this issue I will let you know if I find any other counter-example.

Comment: I don't think there is a counterexample. Here is the statement I'll prove; $X,Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ random independent variables, $g,h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable. Then $g \circ X, h \circ Y$ are independent as well: here is a proof:

Comment: Yes I see now. You're right as can be shown by this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent (what confused me in the beginning is the fact that $A,B$ are disjoint doesn't mean that $g^{-1}(A),g^{-1}(B)$ are disjoint. But I guess it is not as important as I thought).

Comment: Yes, indeed we have $P(g \circ X \in A, h \circ Y \in B) = P(X \in g^{-1}(A), Y \in h^{-1}(B)) = P(X \in g^{-1}(A))P(Y \in h^{-1}(B)) = P(g \circ X \in A) P(h \circ Y \in B)$ for Borel sets $A,B$.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
$$
g_n\colon x\mapsto x\mathbf 1_{\left[-\infty,n\right]}(x).
$$

Comment: Don't you mean $x\mapsto x\mathbf1_{(-\infty,n]}(x)$?

Comment: Yeah I noticed it too but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is immediate that $X\mathbf1_{X_n\leq n}$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(X_n)$ because it is the product of two random variables that are both measurable wrt $\sigma(X_n)$.

That is enough to conclude that also the $X_n'$ are pairwise disjoint.

There is indeed a measurable function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $X_n'=g\circ X_n$.

Let $h:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ denote the function prescribed by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and let $k_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ denote the function  that is prescribed by $x\mapsto(x,\mathbf1_{(-\infty,n]}(x))$.

Both functions can be shown to be measurable so that also their composition is measurable.

Then function $g=h\circ k_n$ will do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Gives more insight.

Comment: You are very welcome.