# stochastically independence

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I never took stochastic courses and need a proof for this task to continue my work at another problem. Can somebody help me out?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be stochastically independent real discrete random variables and $g,h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Show that $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are stochstically independent.

Comment: If $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$, then $P(g(X) \in A, h(Y) \in B) = P(X \in g^{-1}(A), Y \in h^{-1}(B)) = P(X \in g^{-1}(A)) P(Y \in h^{-1}(B))$ under appropriate assumptions.

Comment: See e.g. [Are functions of independent variables also independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent)