# Covariance of X^2 Y^2 when Cov(X,Y) = 0?

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have that X and Y are independent random variables and their covariance is equal to zero, then is the $Cov(X^2, Y^2)$ zero as well? I feel like this is too good to be true, but I cannot come up with a conclusion.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is true.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent it implies their correlation, and therefore covariance are zero (but the converse is not necessarily true).

Assuming this knowledge, then by squaring the RVs separately we are not *inducing* any new correlational information, and thus they still remain uncorrelated and independent.

In this way we conclude $Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X^2,Y^2) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

That the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is zero is a consequence of $X$ and $Y$ being independent. So to say "$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and their covariance is equal to zero" is slightly redundant. As Minus One-Twelfth said, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, and therefore the covariance of $X^2$ and $Y^2$ would be zero.

Independence is necessary. If $X$ has a continuous uniform on the interval $[-1,1]$, and we define $Y = X^2$, then $X$ and $Y$ are of course dependent on each other, but $\text{Cov}[X,Y]=0$ while $\text{Cov}[X^2,Y^2] \neq 0$.