# If two random variables are independent does that mean if one of them is squared then the independency still exists?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are independent. Does that mean $X^2$ and Y are also independent?

Comment: Yes, of course . Independence still exists

Comment: @tommik it doesn't feel right to me, is there any proof you could provide? would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Semiclassical any two constant random variables, even two of the same constant, are independent. (And more generally any constant is independent of any other random variable.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so you confirm what tommik says?

Comment: @Hijaw Yes, more generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for any (measurable) functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables

Comment: In short: $P(f(X)\in A,g(Y)\in B)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A),Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))P(Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(f(X)\in A)P(g(Y)\in B)$. The second equality is a consequence of independence of $X$ and $Y$. This shows that also $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8742/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hijaw, please see [Here](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/%7Egiacomo/Livros/Mood,%20graybill,%20boes%20-%20Introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20statistics.pdf), Theorem 3 page 151 for the statement and proof