# Given positive random variable X and Y, and both are independent. Prove X^2 and Y^2 are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

I understand that:

$X\perp Y$, for any $x$ and any $y$, $x\perp y$.

Then $P(X=x) = P(X=x|Y=y)$.

But I am struggling on giving a reason how $x^2\perp y^2$.

Comment: I don't understand your $Val(X)$ set. Moreover, if $X$ is continuous, $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$, so, it won't take you anywhere. What is you definition of independence ?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff for every $A\in\sigma(X)$ and every $B\in\sigma(Y)$ we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. For Borel-measurable functions $g$ and $h$ we have $\sigma(g(X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(h(Y))\subseteq\sigma(Y)$. So independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies independence of $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $x\perp y$ for real numbers $x$ and $y$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to work with something like $P(X=x|Y=y)$ in general because it is possible that $P(X=x) = 0$ and $P(Y=y)=0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are both normally distributed.  It's usually easier to work with the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

One property equivalent to $X \perp Y$ is $P(X \le x, Y \le y) = P(X \le x)P(Y \le y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.  So to show $X^2 \perp Y^2$, we can show $P(X^2 \le x, Y^2 \le y) = P(X^2 \le x)P(Y^2 \le y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.  If either $x$ or $y$ is negative, both sides will be $0$, so we just need to handle the case $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.  Then we have
\begin{align*}
P(X^2 \le x, Y^2 \le y) &= P(|X| \le \sqrt{x}, |Y| \le \sqrt{y}) \\
&= P(X \le \sqrt{x}, Y \le \sqrt{y}) \\
&= P(X \le \sqrt x)P(Y \le \sqrt y) \\
&= P(X^2 \le x)P(Y^2 \le y),
\end{align*}
where we used that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative to conclude $|X| \le \sqrt x$ iff $X \le \sqrt x$.