# If $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$ , $P(X>YZ)$=?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X, Y, Z$  are i.i.d $N(0,1)$ , $P(X>YZ)$=?

I thought of 2 different ways but both are lengthy and integration is quite tough:

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y*z}^\infty \frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}*\frac{e^\frac{-y^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}*\frac{e^\frac{-z^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
2. By using transformation i.e. finding Distribution of YZ.

Is there any easy way to solve this?  If we take $\frac{X}{Y}$~ $C(0,1)$ but then how we will find joint pdf as $\frac{X}{Y}$ and Z are not independent right? ($Cov(\frac{X}{Y},Z)$= Not Defined)

Comment: For the record, $X/Y$ and $Z$ are still independent.

Comment: how they are independent

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ the distribution of the random variable $X-YZ$ given $Z=z$ is normal with mean equal to $0$, so $P(X-YZ > 0|Z=z) = 1/2$.

Now if we denote $A$ the event that $X-YZ>0$ the law of double expectation says that
$$P(X>YZ)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A] = \mathbb{E}[P(X-YZ>0|Z)]=\mathbb{E}[1/2]=1/2$$

Comment: $E[U]=0$ does not imply $P(U>0)=1/2$. But there is an easy to fix your answer.

Comment: @angryavian You're right, what I wanted to say is that $X-zY$ is a normal r.v. with mean $0$!

Comment: but product of normal is not normal so how X-YZ is a normal random variable

Comment: @AnkitaGoyal When conditioning on $Z=z$, it becomes $X-zY$ which is a linear combination of two independent normal random variables (like $X-2Y$ or $X-3.2Y$).

Comment: ooh okay I got your point . can u please also explain how $\frac{X}{Y}$ and Z are independent.

Comment: "$X - YZ|Z = z$" is not a random variable!

Comment: @Zhanxiong Why not?

Comment: You can say the distribution of the random variable $X - YZ$ given $Z = z$, but that doesn't mean "$X - YZ|Z = z$" is a random variable.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let the CDF of $YZ$ be $F$, $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ be the CDF and PDF of the standard normal random variable.  For any $u \in \mathbb{R}$, by the independence of $Y$ and $Z$, we have
\begin{align}
 & F(u) = P[YZ \leq u] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[Yz \leq u]\varphi(z)dz \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^0 P[Y \geq uz^{-1}]\varphi(z)dz
+ \int_0^\infty P[Y \leq uz^{-1}]\varphi(z)dz \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^0 (1 - \Phi(uz^{-1}))\varphi(z)dz
+ \int_0^\infty \Phi(uz^{-1})\varphi(z)dz.
\end{align}

It then follows by the symmetry of $\varphi$ that
\begin{align}
 & F(-u) = \int_{-\infty}^0 (1 - \Phi(-uz^{-1}))\varphi(z)dz
+ \int_0^\infty \Phi(-uz^{-1})\varphi(z)dz \\
=& \int_0^\infty (1 - \Phi(ut^{-1}))\varphi(-t)dt
+ \int_{-\infty}^0 \Phi(ut^{-1})\varphi(-t)dt \\
=&  \int_0^\infty (1 - \Phi(ut^{-1}))\varphi(t)dt
+ \int_{-\infty}^0 \Phi(ut^{-1})\varphi(t)dt \\
=& \int_0^\infty\varphi(t)dt - \int_0^\infty\Phi(ut^{-1})\varphi(t)dt \\
 & + \int_{-\infty}^0 (\Phi(ut^{-1}) - 1)\varphi(t)dt + \int_0^\infty\varphi(t)dt \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi(t)dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 (1 - \Phi(ut^{-1}))\varphi(t)dt - \int_0^\infty\Phi(ut^{-1})\varphi(t)dt \\
=& 1 - F(u). 
\end{align}

Now by noting $X$ is independent of $YZ$, similar argument as above gives:
\begin{align}
 & I := P[X > YZ] \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[YZ < x]dx \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)\varphi(x)dx \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1 - F(-x))\varphi(x)dx \tag{$F(x) = 1 - F(-x)$} \\
=& 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(-x)\varphi(x)dx \\
=& 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(u)\varphi(-u)du \\
=& 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(u)\varphi(u)du \tag{$\varphi(-u) = \varphi(u)$}\\
=& 1 - I.
\end{align}
Hence $2I = 1$, i.e., $I = 1/2$.

The above argument clearly also generalizes in deriving $P[X_1 > X_2] = 1/2$, where $X_1, X_2$ are independent and both of them are symmetric around $0$.

---

A more direct proof (which is essentially same as the first answer but does not initialize any conditional argument):
\begin{align}
 & P[X > YZ] \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[X > Yz]\varphi(z)dz \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[X - zY > 0]\varphi(z)dz \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(z)dz = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align}

The first equality follows from Theorem 20.3 in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley.  In the third equality, we used $X - zY \sim N(0, 1 + z^2)$ given $X, Y \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$ for any fixed $z \in \mathbb{R}$, whence $P[X - zY > 0] = 1/2$ for every $z$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Good catch.  Fixed it.

Comment: You have some typos around '$I := P[X > YZ] 
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P[YZ < x]dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)\varphi(x)dt $...'

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you so much for validating! Corrected again!